# I can't upload a very long text in to MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I want to upload some text to my MySQL data base. But if the text is longer than 64328 characters it wil upload only first 64328 characters of the text.
How can I fix it?

I use this code to upload text to MySQL database:

```
<? php
//conect to a database
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "my_db");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

//insert a post
$sql="INSERT INTO forum(id, message) VALUES(0, '$message')";
$mysqli->query($sql);
?>
```

Comment: what are you using as a datatype for $message

Comment: i'm using "text" datatype

Comment: How are you populating `$message`? It's possible that you're running up against the server's limit for how much data can be sent with a single HTTP request.

Comment: I want to upload a html code of a table from MS Word and it is about 77000 characters long.

Answer (score 1):

sounds like you need a greater number of characters in your field than message currently supports.

Answer (score 1):

Use text data type in mysql for the message field.. for more info https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html